# Run mysql 'where' clause query in remote machine through ssh in command line

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a requirement of running a mysql query remotely. I am able to run where clause for integer but not string. for example..
Working query..

```
sql_getemail = "ssh root@170.255.39.86 \"mysql -uroot -pabc -e \'select * from mTask where lastindex=5;\' fbdb\""
```

here i am looking for lastindex=5 (integer) but when i need to filter string value like

```
where email like '%@abc.com'
```

then i am not able to prepare correct query.

looking something like

```
sql_getemail = "ssh root@170.255.39.86 \"mysql -uroot -pabc -e \'select * from mTask where email like '%@abc.com';\' fbdb\""
```

saying that something missing in query. I am sure there is an issue with quotes, please help.

Comment: How are you running this command? Your question is tagged with Python 2.7, can you show the Python code you're using?

Comment: making query string as 'sql_getemail'  and then os.system(sql_getemail)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i got the work around.
We can run directly on command prompt all together instead of calling sql file.
keeping `/root/gettable.sh` file on DB box with content like...

```
mysql -uroot -pabc -e "select * from mTask where email like '%@abc.com';"
```

and calling this shell from from source as below...

```
os.system("ssh root@170.255.39.86 /root/gettable.sh")
```

and it gives what i need.